# How to flatten array of struct?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql, flatten

How to change schema in PySpark from this

```
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- device: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- device_vendor: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- device_name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- device_manufacturer: string (nullable = true)
```

to this

```
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_vendor: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_name: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_manufacturer: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `explode` and the `*` selector:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_flat = df.withColumn('device_exploded', F.explode('device'))
            .select('id', 'device_exploded.*')

df_flat.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- device_vendor: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- device_name: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- device_manufacturer: string (nullable = true)
```

`explode` creates a separate record for each element of the array-valued column, repeating the value(s) of the other column(s). The `column.*` selector turns all fields of the struct-valued column into separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

First, take the first array's element using [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.element_at.html#pyspark.sql.functions.element_at), then extract all elements from struct using `*`.

```py
df = df.withColumn('d', F.element_at('device', 1))
df = df.select('id', 'd.*')
```